# Parsing parameter with bracket in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, jquery-bootgrid

I am create table using [Jquery-bootgrid](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Examples/Index#data). in the documentation its passing this kind of parameters to controller

`current=1&rowCount=10&sort[columnName]=asc&searchPhrase=&id=b0df282a-0d67-40e5-8558-c9e93b7befed`

I can get the all parameter value, except the one with bracket `sort[columnName]=asc`, I get the paremeter by create class with same properties name like in parameter

```
public class Bootgrid
{
    public int current { get; set; }
    public int rowCount { get; set; }
    public string searchPhrase { get; set; }
    public string[] sort{ get; set; } //can't get the value
}
```

please advice

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to send a string array when you can send just a string variable for the type of sorting

Comment: Can you try type `IEnumerable<string>` instead of `string[]`?

Comment: `sort` is just a string, not an array. Have you tried with `public string sort{get;set;}` ?

Comment: In any case there's no syntax for query parameter arrays, with each platform/application using its own convention. Some repeat the same name, eg `foo=a&foo=b`. Some use a list of values, `foo=a,b`. Some repeat the name with square brackets `foo[]=a&foo[]=b`

Answer (score 1):

string[] is using int indexes not string indexes.

You can use dictionary for instance.

`public void GetTest(Dictionary<string, string> som)`

This works with Test?som[key1]=value2

where som contains key "key1" with value "value2"